# why is there no picture on the app splash screen

Tags: flutter, android-splashscreen

I want to add a picture to the download screen for android version 12 and above, the color is set, but for some reason the picture is not visible, everything is fine on versions below 12

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">
            @drawable/splash
        </item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

folders with files styles.xml named in the values-v31 style

Comment: <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>

Try from MipMap

Comment: @ShailendraRajput i tried(

Comment: Wired! I think you should use this package -: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

Comment: Is your drawable `AnimationDrawable or AnimatedVectorDrawable`?

Comment: @ShailendraRajput I want to do it without a package(

Comment: @Rahul there is no animation, it's just a png file

Comment: You have put it under animatedIcon which doesn't expect png. Maybe you should try different attribute or make another drawable with background and this png and pass it as background in style.